# На образе Windows XP в Hyper-V нет сетевого подключения

Tags: windows, администрирование, hyper-v

Установил на Hyper-V Windows Xp 32 SP3 для дальнейшей установки Ortacle 9.2, нужно для разработки под эту базу данных. Но доступа в интернет нету, в сетевом подключении подключений нет. В диспетчере устройств нет драйверов, но и закинуть я не могу на виртуалку без сети(шары).
Либо качать iso файл драйверов DrivePack и подсунуть как диск или как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А Hyper-V какой? В 2008-Р2 и 2012-Р2 в консоли виртуальной машины есть кнопка Действие-Вставьте установочный диск служб интеграции. Вставляете его и в гостевой ОС устанавливаете, оно все автоматом ставит...